# How would you handle grouping by weeks across different years?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, date-format

For the analysis that I do, we work with what happened in a given month or week.

For example:

```
SELECT date_format(registration_date, '%Y-%u') as 'cohort', count(id) as 'count' 
FROM account 
GROUP BY `cohort`
```

For months, the changing year doesn't create an issue. Though for weeks, it will create a disjointed week for the last week in 2013 and first in 2014.

Is there any easy way to do groupings based on a rolling 7 day basis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cohort here is "weeks ago". Is this what you mean by a rolling seven day grouping?

```
select
    cast(datediff(current_date(), registration_date) / 7 as unsigned) `cohort`, 
    count(id) `count`
from
    account 
group by
    `cohort`
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a64e/2)</kbd>**